# How to group integrals in sympy?

Tags: sympy

Suppose an expression contains nested integrals, for example:

[image]

I'd like to "group" (not sure if this is the right word) the integrals in the front of the expression, if possible.  The result in this case would be

[image]

I am working with equations that require me to change the order of integration, and I think this form would be more useful.

**Is there an existing function in sympy that would do this?**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: from sympy.abc import x, y

In [3]: a, b = Function('a'), Function('b')

In [4]: Integral(a(x)*b(y), y, x)
Out[4]: 
⌠ ⌠                
⎮ ⎮ a(x)⋅b(y) dy dx
⌡ ⌡
```

**Update:** Because code in comment is awful

```
In [14]: Integral(a(x)*b(y), y, x).doit()
Out[14]: 
⎛⌠        ⎞ ⌠        
⎜⎮ a(x) dx⎟⋅⎮ b(y) dy
⎝⌡        ⎠ ⌡
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a function that will perform the grouping, not the symbolic notation of the result.

Comment: Also, the documentation states that Integral.__new__ takes "an integrand followed by one or more limits."  The rendering (scipy?) seems to think you have made a double integral, but I'm not sure it's right.  Does anyone know?

Comment: This is not just printing, it is actually making this a double integral with a specific order.